# Network SVG Image cant'be load

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I am using the flutter_svg package for network svg images but some images can't be loaded. It shows this error.[image]

I trying with this image and code.

```
SvgPicture.network(
   "https://cdn.coinranking.com/ryY28nXhW/ada.svg",
   height: 20,
   width: 20,
),
```

this link is working fine on the browser.

Comment: Your svg file might be containing some invalid text.

Comment: but it works fine on other platforms like browsers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **DO NOT** attach images of errors. They cannot be copy/pasted, indexed by search engines, and can be blocked by filters. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add your error as formatted text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Answer (score 1):

> https://validator.w3.org/

try this for validating the attached SVG as a correctly-formatted UTF-8 encoded SVG 1.1